# first python program, having trouble looping

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Basically i want my output from previous value to be new input.

```
print ("Welcome to Derivative Risk Calculator")
while True:
    try:
    deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit: "))
    RSK = float(input("Risk: "))
    rate = float(input("Rate: "))
    md = float(input("monthly deposits: "))
    if deposit2<1:
        print ("Not a valid amount, please try again.")
    else:
        break
    except ValueError:
    print ("You have not entered a number. Please enter a valid number")
for month in range(24):
amount = (((deposit2 * RSK) * rate) * 30 + md + deposit2)
new_amount  = amount
print("%4d%21.2f" % (month, new_amount ))
```

Current output:

```
    Enter initial deposit: 55000
Risk: 0.38
Rate: 0.025
monthly deposits: 10000
   0             80675.00
   1             80675.00
   2             80675.00
   3             80675.00
   4             80675.00
   5             80675.00
   6             80675.00
   7             80675.00
   8             80675.00
   9             80675.00
  10             80675.00
  11             80675.00
  12             80675.00
  13             80675.00
  14             80675.00
  15             80675.00
  16             80675.00
  17             80675.00
  18             80675.00
  19             80675.00
  20             80675.00
  21             80675.00
  22             80675.00
  23             80675.00
```

Desired output:

```
    Enter initial deposit: 55000
Risk: 0.38
Rate: 0.025
monthly deposits: 10000
   0             80675.00
   1             113667.00
   2             156063.00
   3             210540.00
```

I basically want each output value of input for next process. For example 80675 becomes the new deposit2 value.

Please help me in this

Comment: Well, you need only 4 monthes, from 0 to 3, but loop to 24.

Comment: Also, make sure your posted program is indented correctly.  The easiest way is to cut-and-paste the original, tested code that reproduces the problem, highlight it and press Ctrl-K to format it as code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you need help with exactly? You say you want to change the value of `deposit2`, but your code never does that. What have you tried? Did you make a typo writing `new_amount` instead of `deposit2`?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which has tips like writing a descriptive title and making a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say: "I basically want each output value of input for next process. For example 80675 becomes the new deposit2 value." Okay, so. Please try to think about the code logically. What is the name of the variable that stores the output variable? **What variable do you want to assign that to?** (Hint: see the part where you said "new deposit2 value"?) Therefore, how should you assign?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to reassign `deposit2` to `amount` for every iteration of the loop. Changing the value of variables is a very common thing to do, and there's nothing wrong with doing it. Also, the variable `new_amount` is not needed, you can simply just change `deposit2` to `amount` once it is calculated. Here's your code, but fixed:

```py
print ("Welcome to Derivative Risk Calculator")
while True:
    try:
        deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit: "))
        RSK = float(input("Risk: "))
        rate = float(input("Rate: "))
        md = float(input("monthly deposits: "))
        if deposit2<1:
            print ("Not a valid amount, please try again.")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print ("You have not entered a number. Please enter a valid number")

for month in range(24):
    amount = (((deposit2 * RSK) * rate) * 30 + md + deposit2)
    deposit2 = amount
    print("%4d%21.2f" % (month, deposit2 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a new "amount" variable equal to the user input (deposit2) to
start and then just update it in the loop.

```
print ("Welcome to Derivative Risk Calculator")
while True:
    try:
        deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit: "))
        RSK = float(input("Risk: "))
        rate = float(input("Rate: "))
        md = float(input("monthly deposits: "))
        if deposit2<1:
            print ("Not a valid amount, please try again.")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print ("You have not entered a number. Please enter a valid number")

amount = deposit2
for month in range(24):
    amount = amount * RSK * rate * 30 + md + amount
    print("%4d%21.2f" % (month, amount))
```